# Ruby on Rails application - No such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to bring up an old Ruby on Rails application from a crashed server, and when I try to access it via the browser, I get this screen:
[image]

For copy-and-paste / searchability, here's the text:

```
Ruby on Rails application could not be loaded
---------------------------------------------
A source file that the application requires, is missing.

    It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
    A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
    no such file to load -- active_record/locking/optimistic
Exception class:
    LoadError
Application root:
    /srv/---REDACTED---/current 
Backtrace:
---the backtrace---
```

That first line mentioned in the backtrace is:

```
include Locking::Optimistic, Locking::Pessimistic
```

So it's looking for active_record/locking/optimistic, which I found in a variety of other locations:

```
/data/srv/---REDACTED---/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to tell Ruby where to go look for the files it thinks are missing. I am not a Ruby person and I don't know how Phusion Passenger runs things, but I know most languages have concepts of "paths" to search and I'm assuming I just need to set a path somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried running a bundle install?

Comment: No. I have no idea what that would do and where to run it from.

Comment: go to the root of the application and run `bundle install` from the terminal. this will install all gems

Comment: Okay, it showed a bunch of "Using <package> (<version>) lines and then ended with a green message "Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /srv/---REDACTED---/shared/bundle" but I'm getting the same error, even after a restart.

Comment: check what active record version is installed, you can check on the output of bundle install, what version it was

Comment: It's version 3.0.20

Comment: so it is the one where the file exist. maybe the permission changed for that folder/file or something. uninstall and reinstall the gem, to see if that change. do it without using sudo, to be sure

Comment: I don't know how to do that. The guy before me was the Ruby guru. It seems just like the application doesn't know where to look for the gem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185094/discussion-between-xploshioon-and-jhilgeman).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually copying over the missing files from the 
/data/srv/---REDACTED---/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb

...to the gem that was reporting the missing file, since it seemed to be the same gem and same version.

Running the bundle install didn't change anything, for some reason.